# Store user settings in map document?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcobjects

I have created a custom tool for ArcMap with .NET and would like to know if there is any way to store user defined settings in a MXD.  The tool simply draws a graphic circle of a certain radius with the center snapped to the closest vertex in a polyline pointed at by the mouse.

Right now, the user has to select the layer and set the radius (with a custom dialog form) every time they open the mxd and use the tool.

This layer and radius rarely changes for a project mxd, so it would be convenient to store the name of the layer and radius setting somewhere, so that it can be automatically used by the tool.

Comment: What sort of user-definable tool settings?  How will you determine the user?  Is it based on Active Directory?  Could you provide a bit more information about your tools and what they do and how they were developed?  I think you need to edit your question to include these details if you'd like a reasonable response.

Comment: Consider trying to store this information in the Windows registry. There will be objects in. Net that will allow you to read and write to it.

Comment: You need to implement an application extension. If the extension also implements relevant persistence interfaces, the saved settings get stored with the MXD document.

Comment: See [How to persist data in a document](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/conceptualhelp/#/How_to_persist_data_in_a_document/00010000027z000000/) for further details.

Comment: @Petr Krebs, that's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement an application extension. If the extension also implements relevant persistence interfaces, the saved settings get stored with the MXD document.

See [How to persist data in a document](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/conceptualhelp/#/How_to_persist_data_in_a_document/00010000027z000000/) for further details.